# How to interpret conflicting results between the binomial and count part of a Zero-Inflated Poisson model?

Tags: poisson-regression, zero-inflation

In my model one of my variables `(X2 below)` is significant and has a negative sign in both the binomial and count parts of a ZIP model. I was wondering how to interpret this? The way I see it, this variable makes the subject less likely to be part of the "always zero" group (thus the negative sign in the binomial part of the model), but actually has a negative effect in increasing the number of counts of the outcome (thus the negative sign in the count part of the model). Would this interpretation be correct?

Here's a copy of my results:

```
Count model coefficients (poisson with log link):
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      -1.748409   2.683158  -0.652 0.514644    
X1                0.028963   0.005909   4.902  9.5e-07 ***
X2               -1.423673   0.412128  -3.454 0.000551 ***
X3                0.577553   0.374920   1.540 0.123446    
X4               -0.037067   0.023975  -1.546 0.122086    
X5               -0.393815   0.541603  -0.727 0.467148    
X6                0.347459   0.142067   2.446 0.014455 *    

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)      12.31313    6.85310   1.797  0.07238 . 
X1                0.01995    0.01744   1.144  0.25244   
X2               -4.19968    1.47908  -2.839  0.00452 **
X3                2.75004    1.22005   2.254  0.02419 * 
X4               -0.27584    0.11146  -2.475  0.01333 * 
X5                2.43214    2.17752   1.117  0.26402   
X6                0.07340    0.41066   0.179  0.85814
```

Comment: Your interpretation looks fine to me. There is no contradiction between the two statements so if you are still concerned perhaps edit in an expansion of your doubts?

Comment: It's just that I find it difficult to think of the variable in this way. ZIP models are a bit tricky to understand and people usually use examples. It would be great if you or anyone else could share an example of such a case.

Comment: Consider using a hurdle model instead of the zero-inflation model. This is typically easier to interpret while leading to a similar overall goodness of fit. (At least I've seen this happening in many examples.)